# WCF client to java webservice getting Message security verification failed on responses

Tags: java, wcf, jboss, jax-ws, ws-security

I'm getting the error "Message security verification failed" on responses coming back from a Java webservice. I don't have control over the Java webservice and I'm not sure how to determine if my client configurations need to be updated.

The following is the inner exception and stack trace:

InnerException:

Bad Data.

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Int32 dwFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(Byte[] rgbIn)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptKey(Byte[] keyData, RSA rsa, Boolean useOAEP)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.DecryptKey(String algorithm, Byte[] keyData)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.DecryptKey(SecurityToken unwrappingToken, String encryptionMethod, Byte[] wrappedKey, SecurityKey& unwrappingSecurityKey)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityJan2004.WrappedKeyTokenEntry.CreateWrappedKeyToken(String id, String encryptionMethod, String carriedKeyName, SecurityKeyIdentifier unwrappingTokenIdentifier, Byte[] wrappedKey, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityJan2004.WrappedKeyTokenEntry.ReadTokenCore(XmlDictionaryReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityTokenSerializer.ReadTokenCore(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroReceiveSecurityHeader.DecryptWrappedKey(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadEncryptedKey(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean processReferenceListIfPresent)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy  extendedProtectionPolicy)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ProcessSecurityHeader(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, Message& message,  SecurityToken requiredSigningToken, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.AsymmetricSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, String actor, TimeSpan timeout,  SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout,  SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
```

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout,  SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply,  SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,  Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Exception rethrown at [0]:

```
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at CICJIS.WebServiceClient.CCISIntegrationWebService.CCISWebServicePortType.executeAsync(executeAsyncRequest request)
at CICJIS.WebServiceClient.GenericWebServiceClient.CallCCISIWSExecuteAsync(String IEPDID, String IEPDPayload)
at CICJIS.WebServiceClient.GenericWebServiceClient.ExecuteAsync(String IEPDID, String IEPDPayload)
at CICJIS.CCISDataProcessing.CCISTransfersDataProcessing.ExecuteAsync(Int32 TranId, String iepdID, String iepdPayload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem. Looks like the java webservice that returns the response had an update to the java version on their server and the ws-security version used was dependent on the old version. They had to point the application back to the older java version.